# Do I need the dregs from primary fermentation for carbonation?

Tags: carbonation, first-time-brewer, primary-fermentation

I'm currently making my first homebrew -  a ginger beer using [this](http://www.madmillie.com/site/madmillie/files/V2_MM_GINGER%20BEER%20Book_LR.pdf) kit and recipe. It's finished primary fermentation (hopefully, the cold weather has me concerned), and I've just bottled it for carbonation. My question is, should I have included the dregs from the primary fermentation jug in the bottles? The recipe says not to shake the jug while bottling, which I took to mean that the dregs weren't meant to be included.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No**. The settled yeast (trub/dregs) from primary shouldn't be included in bottling. There's plenty of yeast in suspension to bottle condition, *unless your cold weather was enough to completely crash and fine in primary.* But that would need to be below 40°F for a couple days.